# SQL LDAP Query Issue

Tags: sql, coldfusion, ldap

Trying to filter AD groups. I've got this that works:

```
SELECT name, distinguishedName    
FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI,'SELECT name, distinguishedName    
FROM ''LDAP://hhsc.org/DC=hhsc, DC=org''    
WHERE objectCategory = ''group'' AND proxyAddresses=''*'' ')    
ORDER BY name
```

It works but we've got email addresses in Security Groups, so I'm trying filter that with this:

```
SELECT name, distinguishedName    
FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI,'SELECT name, distinguishedName    
FROM ''LDAP://hhsc.org/DC=hhsc, DC=org''    
WHERE objectCategory=''group'' AND groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=''2147483648'' ')

ORDER BY name
```

It keeps throwing:

Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT name, distinguishedName
FROM 'LDAP://hhsc.org/DC=hhsc, DC=org'
WHERE objectCategory='group' & groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:='2147483648' " for execution against OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI".

I suspect it's syntax in groupType, but it's got me beat.

FYI that identifier or whatever you call it for groupType works in a CFLDAP query that gives me just my Distribution Lists.

Been working on this off and on for awhile now, but am not making any progress.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do a select * just to see the column names and see if you are referencing them correctly?

Comment: What is the DBMS you are using?  Most likely you need to quote that column name in your WHERE clause.  Like `"groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:" = ...`  _Assuming that is the actual column name_

Comment: @Miguel-F  That was going to be my next suggestion. 

 If it is a column name, quotes or [] around the column may be needed.  In the CFML docs it also says *"In ColdFusion, illegal characters are automatically mapped to the underscore character; therefore, column names in the query result set might not exactly match the names of the LDAP attributes."*

Comment: If I change the syntax on groupType to: ''groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:''=2147483648 ') (Note that's two single quotes around groupType and removed the ' around the number) the query runs, I briefly see the column names and data, but then it goes away and I get Msg 7330 level 16 State 2 Line 1 Cannot fetch row from OLE DB provider "AdsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI". Googling that error, I have Allow inprocess is checked in the ADsDSOObject provider, my windows login to the server is in the local admin group. (Comment Continued)

Comment: Ran the query logged in as SQL sa, same problem. The login account for the linked server is the same login account we use in other similar applications. Thanks

Comment: Do you have over 1000 records being returned from your query?  What happens if you add a TOP 1 to your query?

Comment: It shouldn't be, the record count from the query using proxy addresses is only 740 some records, but I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: Good call, that's what it was, too many lists. I can't believe an organization of our size has some many distribution lists, that's almost half the total number of employees we have. I'll post the working code in case it helps a fellow noob in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: Wait a minute, if I get 740 some records using proxyAddresses="*" (which includes security groups) why am I getting more records when I apply the groupType filter? Seems to me I should get fewer records. There must be something wrong with the way I'm doing that groupType filter.

Comment: I've confirmed that the objectType filter is not working, I'm pretty much getting all groups. I'm trying to incorporate this into the query:   (&(objectCategory=group) 
 (!(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648))) but I either get syntax errors or Msg 7321 errors. Kind of new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps a fellow noob, this works:

```
SELECT name, distinguishedName    
FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI,    
'<LDAP://domainName.com/DC=????,DC=????>;    
(&(objectClass=group)(!(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2147483648)));    
name, distinguishedName;    
subtree')    
ORDER BY name
```

Note, in my case, I found that if I did not put .com, .org or whatever in domain name, it would not work. Also, in my case, I'm running the query from the AD root (I guess that's what you call it)DC=????, DC=???? you can put OU's or CN's in front of that of course.

Server is SQL 2008 R2 64 bit, Active Directory is Server 2003 32 bit. (Yes, we're upgrading.)

On to the next headache!!!